# Unable to install any gem by Ruby in Windows

Tags: rubygems, installation

I've installed rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p195 in my PC and opened command prompt with Ruby.
next i ran `gem update --system` command to update and updated successfully.

Now, whenever I tried to run `gem install <program>`, eg. `gem install rhc`, `gem install af`, its fails to install every time and shows similar **SSL_certificate** related error as shown below -

```
C:\Windows\System32>gem install rhc
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rhc' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/rhc-1.15.6.gemspec.rz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rhc
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

RubyGems fetches gems from the sources you have configured (stored in your
 ~/.gemrc). The default source is `https://rubygems.org`.

But you can execute the following commands: *

```
gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/
gem sources --add http://rubygems.org/
```

<sup>──────────────

* If you want to reset to the «*factory settings*»:

       `gem sources --remove http://rubygems.org/`

       `gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/`</sup>

Comment: Couldn't find `.gemrc` so this way did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you @Paul

Answer (score 16):

This is most likely due to running over a secure (https) connection to rubygems.org. Look at the help for “gem sources –h”, remove the https version and add http://rubygems.org

Comment: My savior! Thank you so much for this question and answer

Answer (score 2):

Windows solution:

1. go to [rubygems download page.](https://rubygems.org/pages/download)
2. download ZIP file.
3. unzip file, then in Command Prompt, going to the path containing ***setup.rb***,  and run this command:

   ruby setup.rb

Answer (score 2):

you can use http for source:

```
gem install rhc --source http://rubygems.org
```